# Why does this //ID pass but //DEF fails?

Tags: xpath, antlr4

I'm experimenting with the XPath using the grammar provided in the test suite and am having a problem with the path `//ID` being identified, but `//DEF` is not found. An `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown. "DEF at index 2 isn't a valid token name" Why is `//ID` matched, but `//DEF`not?

```
String exprGrammar = "grammar Expr;\n" +
"prog:   func+ ;\n" +
"func:  DEF ID '(' arg (',' arg)* ')' body ;\n" +
"body:  '{' stat+ '}' ;\n" +
"arg :  ID ;\n" +
"stat:   expr ';'                 # printExpr\n" +
"    |   ID '=' expr ';'          # assign\n" +
"    |   'return' expr ';'        # ret\n" +
"    |   ';'                      # blank\n" +
"    ;\n" +
"expr:   expr ('*'|'/') expr      # MulDiv\n" +
"    |   expr ('+'|'-') expr      # AddSub\n" +
"    |   primary                  # prim\n" +
"    ;\n" +
"primary" +
"    :   INT                      # int\n" +
"    |   ID                       # id\n" +
"    |   '(' expr ')'             # parens\n" +
"    ;" +
"\n" +
"MUL :   '*' ; // assigns token name to '*' used above in grammar\n" +
"DIV :   '/' ;\n" +
"ADD :   '+' ;\n" +
"SUB :   '-' ;\n" +
"RETURN : 'return' ;\n" +
"DEF:  'def';\n" +
"ID  :   [a-zA-Z]+ ;      // match identifiers\n" +
"INT :   [0-9]+ ;         // match integers\n" +
 "NEWLINE:'\\r'? '\\n' -> skip;     // return newlines to parser (is end-statement signal)\n" +
 "WS  :   [ \\t]+ -> skip ; // toss out whitespace\n";

        String SAMPLE_PROGRAM =
                "def f(x,y) { x = 3+4; y; ; }\n" +
                "def g(x) { return 1+2*x; }\n";

        Grammar g2 = new Grammar(exprGrammar);

        LexerInterpreter g2LexerInterpreter = g2.createLexerInterpreter(new ANTLRInputStream(SAMPLE_PROGRAM));
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(g2LexerInterpreter);
        ParserInterpreter parser = g2.createParserInterpreter(tokens);
        parser.setBuildParseTree(true);
        ParseTree tree = parser.parse(g2.rules.get("prog").index);

         String xpath = "//DEF";
        for (ParseTree t : XPath.findAll(tree, xpath, parser) ) {
            System.out.println(t.getSourceInterval());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, the following gets printed:

```
0..0
18..18
```

In other words:

[image]

;)

This XPath tree pattern matching is all rather new, so my guess is that you've stumbled upon a bug that has been fixed. I'm using ANTLR version 4.2.2

Comment: That's odd because I'm using 4.3 :-S
Also, the indices are wrong. They should be 0..3 and 18..21. Based on my understanding, The DEF token has three characters in and that source interval should give the start and end of the token.

Comment: @JeffreyGuenther yeah, that *is* odd... Don't know if the indexes are supposed to point to the characters, or at the tokens (it would also make sense if it's the latter, in which case the output is expected). If I were you, I'd raise this at the ANTLR4 issue tracker: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues